# Syncronous Scala Future without separate thread

Tags: scala, threadpool, future

I'm building a library that, as part of its functionality, makes HTTP requests. To get it to work in the multiple environments it'll be deployed in I'd like it to be able to work with or without Futures.

One option is to have the library parametrise the type of its response so you can create an instance of the library with type `Future`, or an instance with type `Id`, depending on whether you are using an asynchronous HTTP implementation. (`Id` might be an Identity monad - enough to expose a consistent interface to users)

I've started with that approach but it has got complicated. What I'd really like to do instead is use the Future type everywhere, boxing synchronous responses in a Future where necessary. However, I understand that using Futures will always entail some kind of threadpool. This won't fly in e.g. AppEngine (a required environment).

**Is there a way to create a Future from a value that will be executed on the current thread and thus not cause problems in environments where it isn't possible to spawn threads?**

(p.s. as an additional requirement, I need to be able to cross build the library back to Scala v2.9.1 which might limit the features available in scala.concurrent)

Comment: `Is there a way to create a Future from a value that will be executed on the current thread ` Why use a future then??

Comment: As I explain, to create a consistent return type  across implementations

Comment: I am sorry I did nto understand the question. If you mean that you already have the final value of result and need a future wrapper for it, then how about using a `Promise`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you wish to execute something and then wrap the result with `Future`. In that case, you can always use `Promise`

```
val p = Promise[Int]
p success 42
val f = p.future
```

Hence you now have a `future` wrapper containing the final value `42`

Promise is very well explained [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html) .

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you! Fantastic link as well. The problem here is that you still need to provide an ExecutionContxt (implictly or otherwise). It's not clear to me if the provided ExecutionContext actually gets used with this Promise approach but either way, this ends up like checked exceptions in Java, with the context having to be included all the way through the application that consumes the future.

Comment: Also, the Promise object includes a method to do this a little more concisely: `Promise.successful(42).future`.

Comment: @adamnfish Nope you do not need ExecutionContext for above bit of code. We are not submitting any future any where. I think you are mistaken with it. Just an `import scala.concurrent._` will suffice. Also please accept the answer if you think it answers :)

Comment: And the Future object includes a method to do it even more concisely: `Future successful 42`

Comment: This line doesn't need an ExecutionContext but when you consume that Future (for example by mapping it) you need it there, even though this Future simply wraps a value. Importing `concurrent._` imports the global ExecutionContext so you likely won't see the problem. As I said, it's a requirement that this works without needing a threadpool. For now I've implemented an ExecutionContext myself that runs in the current thread but I'm interested in whether there are solutions that don't require this band-aid.

Comment: @adamnfish You can actually consume the Future without an ExecutionContext by calling the (blocking) `ready` or `result` methods. In your case, since you know the Future will have completed, you know these calls won't block.  On the other hand, using a different ExecutionContext to distinguish the synchronous and asynchronous cases is probably the most natural solution w/ Scala's Future API. This will allow you to pass the Future through code that knows nothing of whether you're actually running in an async context.

Answer (score 1):

Take a [look](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Future.scala) at Scalaz version of Future trait. That's based on top of Trampoline mechanism which will be executing by the current thread unless `fork` or `apply` won't be called + that completely removes all ExecutionContext imports =)

Comment: Very interesting approach, thanks very much. I'd rather not have to include scalaz (especially since the latest version isn't cross built down to 2.9.1), but doing away with ExecutionContext imports would be very handy here.